# Find max of $P=\frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2+1}}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Give $a,b,c>0$ and  $ab+bc+ca=abc$

Find maximum of 
$$P=\frac{2}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2+1}}$$

Could someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get back to an unconstrained problem with the variables
$$
x=  \frac 1a;
y=  \frac 1b;
z=  \frac 1c
$$because
$$
ab+bc+ca=abc \iff x+y+z = 1
$$

Answer (score 0):

hint:

prove the lemma:

$p+q=2t$

$\dfrac{p}{\sqrt{p^2+1}}+\dfrac{q}{\sqrt{q^2+1}}\le \dfrac{2t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}$

"=" will hold when $p=q$

simple differentiate can do it.

then repeat use it.